# Set TextArea as read-only in Flash?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I am new to Flash and I have a TextArea I would like to make read-only so the user can not copy and paste the text.

Is this possible?

Examples or links welcome I dont mind learning ;)

Thanks

Comment: TextArea.editable = true OR false

Answer (score 3):

There is a `editable` property for the TextArea. You can use that. However, I am pretty sure it would be impossible to make it completely copy-paste proof. You can make it hard, though. Perhaps, creating a image out of the text and displaying it would make the text hard to be just copied but not impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use `textArea.textField.selectable` to avoid copy/paste:

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/TextArea.html#textField
- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#selectable

In Flex, `TextArea` has its own `selectable`:

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextArea.html#selectable

Answer (score 1):

All you need do is, right click on the textarea you placed on your web page. Then from the pop-up window, click on "edit tag" OR press "Shift + F5". The property window for textarea will be dispayed. Click on the General option if not already selected. Then simply click on the "read only check box" in the property window. You can also prevent the content of textarea box from being selected, copy and paste by checking the "disabled check box".

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a class I quickly made that you might find useful:

```
package
{
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;

    public class BitmapText extends Bitmap
    {
        // vars
        private var _textf:TextField;

        /**
         * Draws text onto the bitmap
         * @param tf The TextField to draw
         */
        public function drawText(tf:TextField):void
        {
            _textf = tf;

            bitmapData = new BitmapData(tf.width,tf.height,true);
            bitmapData.draw(tf);
        }

        /**
         * Update text
         * @param t The new text
         */
        public function set text(t:String):void
        {
            if(_textf)
            {
                _textf.text = t;
                drawText(_textf);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to use this class:

```
var t:TextField = new TextField();
t.text = "some copy";

var bt:BitmapText = new BitmapText();
bt.drawText(t);

addChild(bt);

bt.text = "some new text lol";
```

As you can see, you can easily update the text via:

```
BitmapText.text = "new value";
```

Comment: Seems like overkill. Setting the TextArea editable tag will provide the same amount of protection *as far as I know*. If someone wanted to copy the text, in both cases they'd have to decompile the SWF and find the line of code with that text (and who would do that?).

Comment: True, honestly I didn't even know there was an editable/selectable property haha.

Comment: @Benjammin' - I have editable unselected but that just means they cant add text to the box they can still highlight to copy and paste. It can be down for a dyanic text area so thought it could also for a component TextAra.

Comment: Try my new answer for dynamic text.